# undefined control sequence '\For' - algorithmicx package

Tags: algorithmicx

I have to write some algorithm, thus I've decided to use algorithmicx package:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \For{aa}
            \State $Sim(i,j) \gets \frac{v_{i} \cdot v_{j}}{\left|v_{i}\right|\left|v_{j}\right|}$
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
    \label{alg:rAP}
    \caption{algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
```

Everything is fine but LaTeX says`Undefinde control sequence \For`

I'm very confused because I've just follow the instruction of `algorithmicx`

Also there is no problem to use `\State` (when I've commented out `\For`)

I've also tried `\FOR`, `\for` but nothings work.

Seems `algorithmicx` package are not deprecated and it makes me more confused.

Comment: You have to load `algpseudocode` and not `algorithmicx`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. However, the instruction says as if algorithmicx also works. Is it wrong? http://cs.indstate.edu/CS695/algorithmicx.pdf , page 7.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `algorithmicx` documentation:

> The package `algorithmicx` itself doesn’t define any algorithmic commands, but gives a set of macros to define such a command set. You may use only `algorithmicx`, and define the commands yourself, or you may use one of the predefined command sets.
>
> These predefined command sets (layouts) are:
>
> `algpseudocode`...
>
> `algcompatible`...
>
> `algpascal`...
>
> `algc`...

This means that loading the `algorithmicx` package only, you have to define yourself the commands.

If you want to use one of the predefined sets of commands, you have to load the corresponding package, in your case `algpseudocode`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \For{aa}
            \State $Sim(i,j) \gets \frac{v_{i} \cdot v_{j}}{\left|v_{i}\right|\left|v_{j}\right|}$
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
    \label{alg:rAP}
    \caption{algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]